# Convergence of $k\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{k}]}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, characteristic-functions

If we define $\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{k}]}$ to be a characteristic function such that

$\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{k}]}(x)=\begin{cases}
1 ~~~ \text{if $x\in [0,\frac{1}{k}]$} \\
0 ~~~ \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$

How do we show that the function $k\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{k}]}$ does not converge to a function $f$ point wise so that $\int |f_k-f| \rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$? I am lost since when $k\rightarrow \infty$ we have $\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{k}]}\rightarrow \chi_{[0,0]}$. The part that confuses me the most is if its true that $k\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{k}]}\rightarrow \infty \cdot 0 = 0$ or $=\infty$? Or is this reasoning correct?

Comment: I think you should point out what kind of convergence you really want to know

Comment: for example, in norm-wise, point-wise or uniform wise

Comment: Edited the post to include this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions converge pointwise to the function $0$ **except** at the origin. But the measure of the set $\{0\}$ equals to zero, so it does not matter what they converge to at the origin, so set it to $0.$ Then $f=0,$ but $\int |f_n|$ does **not** go to zero. Contradiction.